# Material Properties - missing Features

Tags: materials, interface

I want to add a new material in Blender, and instead of showing a long list of menu like "previews", "surface", etc., all I get is "view port display" and Customer property".

[image: Material Properties]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your Render Engine is set to "Workbench".**

Set it either to "Eevee" or "Cycles", depending which one you want to use in your project.

[image: material properties workbench, cycles, eevee]

Comment: ! Thank you so much! This saved my day!

Comment: @YihongDing - If this answer solved your problem, instead of "Thanks", please mark it as "[accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)".